# Java - How to Differ 2 Microphone with 1 port

Tags: java, audio

I Have 1 microphone port on my laptop. And i split it using microphone spliter so i can use 2 microphone with 1 port. The splitter is like this pic !

[splitter](http://www.racelogic.co.uk/Store/product_images/i/911/RLCAB095-_VVB-L_Mic_Splitter_Cable__41312_zoom.jpg)

My question is, how can i differ which microphone is the data belongs to with Java ?

Comment: So you have a left and a right channel?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html set the channels value to 2

Comment: owh thanks for the link @balazs_gunics

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the splitter just splits left and right channel, each to one microphone (so you can record two mono channels). If your laptop supports stereo input, which is also very likely, you can easily distinguish between the signals simply by selecting only left or only right channel (or both and properly postprocess the buffer if you want record both microphones simultaneously.)